# I changed the Wordpress date format but it doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

I changed the date format in the WordPress settings, but I still have the date displayed in the format "2024-02-15", whereas I want a French format "15-02-2024".

I've tried different code to add to function.php, but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
function custom_wordpressbox_loop_date($date_fmt) {
return 'l, F j, Y';
};
add_filter('wordpressbox_loop_date', 'custom_wordpressbox_loop_date');
?>
```

Thank you for your help.
Aymeric

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the date format for the whole website you can go to the **Dashboard -> Settings -> General -> Date Format**.

If you need to format a particular date in your code you can use the `date()` function in PHP:

```
date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($date_string));
```

Comment: Thanks, as I explained! I've already modified in Dashboard -> Settings -> General -> Date Format, but the format doesn't change. I can't see what the problem is.

For the code :
date("l, F j, Y", strtotime($date_string));
I'm not very good at coding, can you give me the whole code to integrate it into function.php?

Thanks in advance,
Aymeric